# Git: revert entire repository

Tags: git, version-control

> **tl;dr**: Revert my *entire local repository* to a specific point in time. I want all branches to be reverted to that point. I want all
>   commits that came after that point in time to be completely gone. I guess a good way of depicting it would be to cut off all the tips of all the branches (as you would see in SourceTree) that are newer than a specific time.

Let's say I have 3 branches that each implement "a way of doing it". In fact I want to keep these three branches completely separate. However, when I find a bug, I want to fix it in all three branches, for example. That's where I made a mistake, and I'm trying to fix it in a git-way. I merged the wrong branch into the all of these three branches. (The the way git merges branches is slightly different than I expected.) In fact, I'd love to revert the **entire git repository** to the the last **point in real-life time** where it was ok.

I've been trying for hours now to do this. I tried using `git reset --hard <commit>`, but that doesn't revert the repository itself. Only the working directory, it seems.

Comment: `git reset --hard` DOES revert the repository, not just the working directory. However, if you have a remote repository (to which you have already pushed the commits you have `reset`ed in the local repo), you will need to `git push -f` it, otherwise whenever you `pull` from it, you will get the reset-ed commits back to your local repo

Comment: Btw, a pictorial representation of the status of your current repo and the repo you want could be useful. Right now I'm assuming a situation like what @torek assumes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short version

It sounds like you want three separate `git reset --hard`s.

#### TL;DR Long version

Let me draw a graph that I think represents what you had before (and want to get back to), and what you had after:

```
  --- x           <-- badbranch
 /
... - o - o - o   <-- branch1
 \
  \-- o - o - o   <-- branch2
   \
    - o - o       <-- branch3
```

This is "before you did three merges": `branch1` had at least 3 unique commits, `branch2` had at least 3 unique commits, and `branch3` had at least 2 (these are the `o` nodes).

Meanwhile, a fourth branch (`badbranch` above) had a "bad" commit `x`.

You then did:

```
$ git checkout branch1; git merge badbranch
$ git checkout branch2; git merge badbranch
$ git checkout branch3; git merge badbranch
```

(plus possible resolvings, but I'll assume the merges all merged easily *and* created merge commits, below).

Just as a reminder, what `merge` does is get two diffs, one for the current branch tip (let's say `branch1`) vs the merge-base (somewhere back in the `...` series of commits), and one for the to-be-merged tip (`x`) vs that same merge-base.  It then applies the diff from base-to-`x` to the tip of the current branch after screening away all the changes that are already in the base-to-tip diff; and if all goes well, it makes a new commit from the result:

```
  --- x               <-- badbranch
 /     `---------\
... - o - o - o - M   <-- branch1
```

We don't need to look at `branch2` and `branch3` yet, but if we want to, it helps to temporarily ignore `branch1`.  Let's draw in just `branch3` this time, including its merge (which we'll call `M3` to distinguish it from `M`):

```
  --- x           <-- badbranch
 /      \
...      \
 \        \
  \        \
   \        \
    - o - o - M3   <-- branch3
```

---

Now let's look at what `git reset` does, graph-wise.  (You already know that with `--hard` it resets your work-tree.)

Let's go back to just considering `branch1`:

```
$ git checkout branch1
```

which has the bad merge `M` on it.  I'll expand the drawing to make it a bit taller for reasons that will become obvious, and then I'll move `M` up likewise:

```
    - x               <-- badbranch
   /    \
  /      ------ M     <-- branch1
 /             /
... - o - o - o
```

(With any luck it's still obvious that despite now looking like a cartoon dog's head, it's the same graph as before).

When you run `git reset` with a commit-ID—or with a name that specifies a commit-ID—it looks at the current branch (now `branch1`) and moves that label to the target commit.  In this case, let's say you use `HEAD^` or the commit-ID of the tip-most `o`; either one gives the same result, of moving `branch1` back down to point to the `o`.  Now the graph is:

```
    - x               <-- badbranch
   /    \
  /      ------ M
 /             /
... - o - o - o       <-- branch1
```

The "bad" merge commit `M` is no longer directly visible, because the view you get (with `git log` or graphical viewers) starts from the branch tips, which no longer display the merge commit `M`.  So what you see is this:

```
    - x               <-- badbranch
   /
  /
 /
... - o - o - o       <-- branch1
```

which is what you had before you did the merge.

Of course, branches `branch2` and `branch3` still have their "bad" merges, but you can fix that easily by checking out *those* branches and doing `git reset --hard HEAD^` while on each of those branches.

Each reset backs up the current branch one commit, to the place it was before you did the "bad" merge.  You must repeat for each commit since each branch was and still is separate, since each merge was a real merge, not a "fast forward".

---

If some branch(es) *did* get a "fast forward", you must be a little bit more careful: `HEAD^` may no longer suffice for each reset.  But in general, resetting each branch to the desired commit-ID, which you can find in the reflogs for those branches, will do the trick.

Comment: Is that `HEAD^` a typo? As far as I know it should be either `HEAD` (to be used if merge has not been committed) or `HEAD~1` (someting like `HEAD` - 1, so it is to be used if merge has already been committed)

Comment: No, `HEAD^` means the same as `HEAD~1` (and  `HEAD^^^` means the same as `HEAD~3`, and so on).  Note that `HEAD^2` is quite different though: the `^` suffix lets you specify which parent-link to use, while the `~` suffix lets you specify how many times to traverse a first-parent link.  Some command shells treat `^` and/or `~` specially (depending on where they appear) so some people prefer one or the other.  I tend to use `HEAD^` instead of `HEAD~1` myself but my shell doesn't treat them specially except in *leading* positions (so trailing is OK).

Comment: Thank you very very much, for both of your answers :) You guessed the situation right. The problem was that pretty much all of my merges automatically did fast-forward. Another problem was that I already pushed it to my remote. The fast-foward was the real struggle in the process of reseting hard. Now I found `--no-ff` and this works great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `git reset --hard <commit>` reverts both the information in the repository regarding your current branch and your working directory (without `--hard` it only reverts the information in the repository and leaves your working directory untouched).

If you only have three branches, the easiest thing to do is just `git checkout` each branch and then `git reset --hard <commit>` to some commit meeting your requirements.

In place of `<commit>`, you can also use a time specification, like `HEAD@{yesterday}`, which might simplify things a bit. See the `SPECIFYING REVISIONS` section of the [git-rev-parse man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) for details on specifying dates (and the myriad other ways in which you can refer to commit objects).

If you had more than a few branches you could probably automate things a bit, possibly starting with `git for-reach-ref refs/heads/` for a list of branches, but I haven't worked through that particular solution yet.